# How are unsubscribes tracked in Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber, email-studio, unsubscriber

I have a bumped into a weird scenario, which requires me to refresh my understanding of Salesforce Marketing Cloud activity tracking for Emails. To add some context, we use Salesforce Sales Cloud as well as the Marketing Cloud, but we do not use/want to use subscription status in Salesforce Marketing Cloud. These preferences are built out at the lead level in our Salesforce CRM instance. Also, all of our emails have the unsubscribe option/link which takes a customer to our website where they need to confirm that they want to unsubscribe. Does Salesforce Marketing Cloud track the unsubscribe activity as soon as they click the link? I haven't been able to replicate this by clicking on the links myself, but have seen subscribers marked as unsubscribed in the Marketing Cloud when they have unsubscribe activity as part of a certain send. This results in some cases when a customer has not unsubscribed in Salesforce CRM, but are marked as unsubscribed in the Marketing Cloud Subscribers List. Is there a way to not have them be unsubscribed in Marketing Cloud when they click the link? Also, is my understanding of the process correct?

Note: Subscribers marked as unsubscribed after a certain number of hard bounces. is a behavior that is expected and something that we do not wish to work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that the unsubscribes you see are coming from email clients  like gmail? See below.

[Gmail's Unsubscribe Function: What You Need to Know](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2014/03/gmails-unsubscribe-function-what-you-need-to-know.html)

> Does ExactTarget track and process these unsubscribe requests? Yes. We receive and process all requests. We mark the respective recipient as "unsubscribed" in our system. We tie the unsubscribe request back to the specific send in question, so it will be reflected in your post-send statistics.

Comment: webdrup is likely right. This is the List-Unsubscribe header (http://www.list-unsubscribe.com/) which has most recently added iOS10  mail on top of the other supported clients, like Gmail.  This offers the option of auto-unsub by POST to URL OR unsub by email reply via a button in UI.  Your option is to likely talk to support and see if you can remove the POST option in your headers. or this option altogether. I would be wary though as this can affect your complaint and engagement rates as well as potentially directly affecting deliverability as well.